# hide the content when the mouse out

Tags: jquery

html

```
<ul class="nav-tabs">
  <li class="tab1"><a href="/" class="tab-link">Home</a></li>
  <li class="tab2 active"><a href="/" class="tab-link">...</a></li>
  <li class="tab3"><a href="/" class="tab-link">...</li>
  <li class="tab4"><a href="/" class="tab-link">...</li>
</ul>

<div id="tab-content">
  <div class="tab2"></div>
  <div class="tab3"> </div>
</div>
```

when the mouse hove on the nav-tabs li. the corresponding div content in tab-content show. when leave out the nav-tabs li. the corresponding div content show.

jquery:

```
$( ".nav-tabs li" ).hover(
  function() {
     $( "#tab-content div" ).css( "display", "block" );
  }, function() {
     $( "#tab-content div" ).css( "display", "none" );
  }
);
```

there is something wrong with the code. when the the corresponding div in `tab-content`  part show. i can't move the mouse on its child a link. 
2, when i hove on another `nav-tabs li`. the other li content also shows.
 how to correct it? thank you.

Comment: Please cleanup your code

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".nav-tabs li").hover(function () {
    $("#tab-content div." + this.className.match(/(tab\d+)/)[0]).show();
}, function () {
    $("#tab-content div." + this.className.match(/(tab\d+)/)[0]).hide();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QpW8D/)

Comment: thank u. all of are ok.but when the mouse leave out ".nav-tabs li". the #tab-content div... not hide.

Comment: in the demo example. first,tab2 tab3 content are hidden. when i leave out the li. tab2 content are hidden.thank u.

Comment: @stack2013a sorry can you explain it again